# Room doesn't execute AddNewCallback

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, dagger-2, android-room

I am trying to init data with RxJava2, Dagger2 and Room and MVP in Android, but Android doesn't execute my room callbacks.

This is my method that creates database, and this is what I see in logs:

```
public synchronized static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = buildDatabase(context);
   }
   return INSTANCE;
}

private static AppDatabase buildDatabase(Context context) {
    Log.i("jestem", "builddatabase");

    RoomDatabase.Callback callback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.i("jestem", "oncreatebuildda22tabase");
            super.onCreate(db);
          Single.just(getInstance(context).initData());
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            getInstance(context).onOpenDb();
            super.onOpen(db);
        }
    };

    return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
            AppDatabase.class,
            "pijatyka.db")
            .addCallback(callback)
            .build();}

public static void onOpenDb() {
    Log.i("jestem", "onopendb");
    hasFinishedCreating = true;

}

public boolean initData() {
    Log.i("Im here", "oncreatebuilddatabase");
    for (Cards card : DataGenerator.initCards()
            ) {
        myDAO().insertCard(card);
    }
    for (Awards award : DataGenerator.initAwards()
            ) {
        myDAO().insertAwards(award);
    }
    hasFinishedCreating = true;
    return true;
}
```

But I don't see any of this in logs, and I don't know why...inside the function `onCreate` and `onOpen`

This is my activity module:

```
@Module
public class StartModule {

    private final StartActivity activity;


    public StartModule(StartActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @StartScope
    public Activity activityProvides(){
        return  activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @StartScope
    public  StartView view(){
        return new StartView(activity);
    }

    @Provides
    @StartScope
    public StartPresenter presenter(StartView view, StartModel model){
        return new StartPresenter(view, model);
    }

    @Provides
    @StartScope
    public StartModel model(AppDatabase database){
        return new StartModel(activity, database);
    }
}
```

And my application module

```
@Module
public class MyAppModule {
    private final Context context;

    public MyAppModule(Application application){
        context = application.getApplicationContext();
    }


    @MyAppScope
    @ApplicationContext
    @Provides
    public Context context(){
        return context;
    }


    @MyAppScope
    @Provides
    public AppDatabase appDatabase(@ApplicationContext Context context){
         return AppDatabase.getInstance(context);
    }

    @Provides
    @MyAppScope
    public MyDAO providesMyDao(AppDatabase database){
        return database.myDAO();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from `just` won't be executed until you subscribe to the `Single` object, so change:

```
Single.just(getInstance(context).initData());
```

to

```
Single.just(getInstance(context).initData())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())   // init Data off main thread
    .subscribe();                   // pass some results handler, if you need
```

Example of result handlers:

```
Single.just(getInstance(context).initData())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(result -> {
            if(result)
                System.out.println("Init successful");
            else
                System.out.println("Init unsuccessful");
        }, error -> {
            System.out.println("Error occurred: " + error);
        });
```

Comment: "Init succesful" should be in Logcat? i dont see them

Comment: Have you run any type of query on your database? The database is lazily created on a first access, so If you didn't, it won't get created and thus the `onCreate` won't be executed

Comment: I didnt try yet, Maybe this is problem... Give  me 10 minutes :d

Answer (score 0):

```
'   private Disposable isFinishedCreatingDataBase(){
      //  return model.hasFinishedCreating()
        return Single.just(appDatabase.hasFinishedCreating)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .repeat()
                .subscribe(n -> {
                    if(n==true){
                        startNewActivity();
                    }
                    Log.i("show", String.valueOf(n));
                }); '
```

i subscribe them, but in the presenter sorry :D im not write this here..
:/

Comment: unfortunately nothing change, but thank you I didn't see this :D